# How to select from dynamic drop downs in watir

Tags: html, watir

I am trying to automate login. It generates a list of databases based on username and password.
I tried something like

```
Browser.text_field(:id,"comboDatabase").when_present.set "(tas01) jazz tst DSS GM QA 20120110.1"
```

But it does not work the way expected.
Any help is appreciated.
Here is the html for that page

Comment: I don't see the html for the page. What did you expect and what did it do?

Answer (score 0):

To address a drop down, you should use Browser.select_list( :id, 'comboDatabase' ).select( "(tas01) jazz tst DSS GM QA 20120110.1")

I can imagine you are referring to some sort of javascript autocomplete. In that case and as Dave points out, the HTML/URL would help.